# VB Using variable name to access control properties

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set the Text property of a dynamically created text box using a variable name, but when I use the Me.Controls(variable name).Text, I'm getting an error saying I need to set it up as "New". The name property of the text box, using a variable, was set when it was created but I don't seem to be able to retrieve using the same name.

```
    Private Sub Example(panposition As Integer)

    Dim tbfile = New TextBox()
    Dim lineExample As Integer = 2
    ' creating a text box with a variable name
    Controls.Add(tbfile)                    ' create the new textbox to hold the file name
    tbfile.Name = "tbfile" + panposition.ToString
    tbfile.Location = New Point(85, tvposition)
    tbfile.Size = New Size(155, 20)
    tbfile.Text = "file name"
    tbfile.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left
    tbfile.HideSelection = False
    tbfile.TabStop = False
    tbfile.AllowDrop = False
    tbfile.Visible = True

    ' trying to update the text in the text box using file name and text retrieved from an array
    Me.Controls.(arrTextVals(1, lineExample)).Text = arrTextVals(2, lineExample)


End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  I cant see where the name of the New TextBOx is added to `arrTextVals`.  A list or perhaps a Dictionary (depending on what the other info in it is), might work better

Comment: Try using DirectCast to get to your control

Comment: Try adding the control after you set the properties.

Comment: The values of arrTextVals are set outside the sample code that I put in the query. I have used MessageBox to determine that the value is correct for the text box that I'm trying to update. I have move the Controls.Add statement to after the parameters are set and I seem to be getting farther. Now I'm getting a BC30203 error saying an identifier is expected. I'm pretty new to this - can anyone help? Someone suggested that I use Direct Cast but I'm not familiar with that yet.

Comment: BTW, the array where I'm retrieving the text box name is a string array. Do I need to convert this to an object type before I use it in the statement to update the text? How would I do that?

Comment: You need to include the applicable code and complete error message and location of you want help.  There is no "set it up as "New"" error message and we gave to guess what and where "identifier is expected" is happening

Comment: The BC30203 error code is happening on the following line:                 Me.Controls.(arrTextVals(1, bottomLine)).Text = arrTextVals(2, bottomLine)

Comment: As mentioned above, I have checked the array value that I am using in the Me.Controls statement. It is a string value of "tbfile1". I'm wondering if I need to convert this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in line:

```
Me.Controls.(arrTextVals(1, lineExample)).Text = arrTextVals(2, lineExample)
```

The correct way to address a control in this way is to make a reference like this

```
Me.Controls(i).Text = arrTextVals(2, lineExample)
```

where i is an integer or using the name of the desired control which in your case could be

```
Me.Controls(arrTextVals(1, lineExample)).Text = arrTextVals(2, lineExample)
```

Of course i suppose as you mentioned before that arrTextVals is a string array

**Edit:**

You have a dot after Me.Controls.( <- never put a . before a bracket.